# Unable to get sonar-fortify plugin configured with Jenkins and SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I have scoured the forums and cannot seem to quite understand the config for the fortify plug-in with Sonar.

I understand it simply builds a widget based on data from a previously generated .fpr file.
My setup:

- Maven 3 project
- Jenkins 1.606
- SonarQube 5.0.1
- Sonar-Fortify plug-in 2.0

Prerequisites:

- .fpr file is in Jenkins workspace
- Sonar is added to pom.xml
- sonar-fortify-plug-in v2.0 added to pom.xml - (wasn’t sure this was needed or not)
- Sonar server configured in Jenkins
- sonar fortify plug-in v2.0 added to Sonar – (only see a dropdown to ‘enableReportLink’ under ‘Configure widgets’
  should there be more config somewhere?

Questions:

- Where should this property be set? Jenkins Sonar config, Sonar, pom file?
  sonar-runner -Dsonar.fortify.reportPath=/path/to/project.fpr
- Is that path to the .fpr file where it is within the Jenkins workspace?

The setup instructions on Github seem short and I feel I am missing something specific in my understanding.

Any help or direction to additional documentation is great appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all [as documented](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Fortify+Plugin) version 2.0 can not be used anymore. Version 2.1 is going to be released soon. Vote for release will be started this week. Meanwhile you can:

- download [2.1-SNAPSHOT version](http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-fortify-plugin/2.1-SNAPSHOT/sonar-fortify-plugin-2.1-20150309.094749-1.jar) and copy it in extensions/plugins of your SonarQube server installation
- restart server. The Fortify rules should be available in the page "Rules".
- execute Fortify command "sourceanalyzer", independently from SonarQube. It generates a report file suffixed by .fpr.
- execute a standard SonarQube analysis of your project by adding the property sonar.fortify.reportPath, for example:

  mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.fortify.reportPath=/path/to/project.fpr

  sonar-runner -Dsonar.fortify.reportPath=/path/to/project.fpr

If everything works, then you can automate these steps in Jenkins.

Comment: Must fortify rules be 'Activated' in order for the plug-in to simply build the graph widget?

Comment: Yes, that's the principle of SonarQube. Issues are raised only on the rules enabled in Quality profiles.

Comment: I have made progress but still not quite there yet. I have successfully got the plugin installed, and all rules activated and associated with the 'sonar way' quality profile. The scan completes successfully and Sonar displays the 4 quadrant grid and 'Fortify Security Rating'. Unfortunately it is displaying 5/5 and all 0's even though on my fortify server there are issues identified. Is there additional configuration I am missing or have misconfigured?

Comment: I messed around with installing additonal language plugins for javascript and css. This did not change anything in relation to the generated fortify graphs or evalution numbers.

Comment: Is it a multi-modules maven project ? Could you attach logs please ?

Comment: Yes it is a multi-module project consisting of a parent pom, then EAR, EJB, and WAR module each with their own pom. I have drilled down to the dashboard of the EJB and WAR to see if the plugin displayed differently there, it did not. I will pull some logs from Sonar and the Maven run and post them here soon.

Comment: Maven<br/> ? <br/>sonar.log<br/>

Comment: [INFO] [08:53:44.145] Sensor Fortify sensor...
[INFO] [08:53:44.146] Process Fortify report...
[INFO] [08:53:44.670] Process Fortify report done: 524 ms
[INFO] [08:53:44.671] Sensor Fortify sensor done: 526 ms
[INFO] ccm-pom ............................................ SUCCESS [01:02 min]
[INFO] CCM EJB ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] CCM WAR ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] CCM ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: The maven output after running sonar:sonar with the fortify path it always shows the parent pom as success and then each module as 'SKIPPED' even though the analysis information, code coverage, etc. definitely includes the sub modules. Is this an indicator that I have something configured incorrectly and is it related to what I am seeing with the sonar fortify plugin?

Comment: I am struggling with formatting here, sorry. The only fortify specific log entries I find are the one in the maven out put. Nothing in the sonar.log or analysis_reports.log

Comment: You should give a try with a single-module project, just to be sure that environment is correctly configured. Moreover you can use gist.github.com to share logs.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion of gist.github, was looking for a solution to sharing long log files.